# Keras Sequence2Sequence example runs out of memory

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to start learning a bit of sequence 2 sequence modeling as I haven't really done much with LSTM's and embeddings before. I'm using the Keras example from their site.

https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html

The github of the script:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py

The script runs fine if I run it with 'num_samples' limited to a low number like 10k. If I remove the num_samples restriction and train on the 124k items it will train properly for several epochs then OOM randomly along the way.

As the epoch train the memory gradually rises from a few gigs to maxing out my 32GB machine. After a successful epoch is trained the memory flushes and drops back down to only a few gigs again. Then repeats this raising and lowering on the next epoch until eventually it dies.

Since I'm training on much smaller batches, I don't get why the memory raises constantly. I would think it would never need to allocate more than is needed for a batch. Anyone more knowledgeable than me about Keras LSTM's able to look at the example and see why the memory balloons, or is this required and I don't understand something?

Edit: I've noticed if I limit the number to 100k I don't see the out of control memory usage but I do at 124k. My assumption is that is because somewhere in between I stop being able to fit everything into GPU memory :( Not sure what that means. I would expect my total dataset to not have to fit into memory.

Comment: I think a possible problem is because of `stateful` in LSTM. At the beginning of each epoch, the hidden state will be randomly initialized again, thus the memory flushes. During training, it is kept (both hidden and cell states) so the memory rises.

Comment: @AerysS so I found out if I limit the amount to ~100k items instead of the full 124k the CPU side doesn't do it. That seems to indicate I see the out of control memory once the entire dataset stops fitting into GPU memory :(

Comment: Have you tried using the examples from 100k to 124k? Maybe one of the inputs is exceptionally long and/or requires an exceptionally long output

Comment: [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/nlp/lstm_seq2seq.py) now seems to be here... I'm not going to read it, but cheak if "memory leaks" in your code [your problem can be not about LSTM, but about its use in certain implementation]